# Autocorrelation not as expected

Tags: python, autocorrelation

I am trying to find the autocorrelation function on the intensity of a pixel over time stored in an array "Intensity". Usually one would expect the highest point to be at t = 0 and then decay. I am getting a random mess.[image]

I checked my code with multiple posts on here regarding autocorrelation such as [Autocorrelation: numpy versus FFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54924/autocorrelation-numpy-versus-fft) I am working in python

```
correlation = np.correlate(Intensity, Intensity, mode='full')/Intensity.size    
correlation = correlation[correlation.size//2:]     
plt.plot(range(0,len(correlation)),correlation)     
plt.show()
```

You might say well maybe your data looks very similar all around, but then either way why would the highest value not be at t = 0? its not even close. I feel like I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Hi: At $t=0$, you have the lag zero autocorrelation which is  the standard deviation of the process ( so not really an autocorrelation).   It can be shown that the sd of any process is always greater than all of its other autocorrelations.

Comment: @markleeds that's exactly Mornet's question: why *isn't* the graph showing that. (also, lag zero is *really* an autocorrelation, just like any other lag, if you ask me; treating it special just complicates a lot of math).

Comment: Mornet, I'd agree with you mathematically. However, I can't run your code to verify this is being a bug in numpy or just a visualization problem. Could you either supply a complete example that we can run, or check the value of `correlation[0]` and `max(abs(correllation))` manually?

Comment: @Marcus Muller: Thanks. My bad. I didn't realize that the plot shown was that of the autocorrelations.  Definitely something is wrong because correlations should of course be between -1.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Yes I can! I ran "print(correlation[0], ' ', max(abs(correlation)))" and it shows "5.6644   13.0998"

Comment: I manually coded a correlation function and I do get an exponential decay looking graph, still have no idea what is wrong with the numpy code. My code takes extremely long to run so I am still interested in this :(

Comment: I find the dsp way of calculating correlation to be extremely confusing so I'm not going to try to understand this link but it might be useful to you. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html